# Issues while attempting to open a java project with Netbeans on Ubuntu Mate 15.10

Tags: java, jdk, netbeans

Well, i just moved from windows and installed Netbeans to do some java projects, but I can't manage to open, either my old projects or even a new one. Here's some screenshots:

[while attempting to open an old project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKEyc.png)

[And for a new one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g8D2.png)

It's weird it says JDK is missing since, as you can see, everything needed is installed:

```
daniel@daniel-VGN-NR230FE:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

And this is it! Thanks for your attention! :)

Comment: You have JRE, not JDK. Run `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` to install it

Comment: Thanks, I will! Sorry my question was a bit silly :P And, by the way, is there any substantial difference between openjdk and oracle jdk?

Comment: OpenJDK is easier to install and works better on Ubuntu. It's also Open Source. Can you tell me if that works, so I can add it as an answer, and you can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have JRE installed, not JDK. NetBeans needs JDK to work properly. Install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```